# Spring Data JPA Query: MYSQL TO @QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Can someone please translate me the following mysql query to @Query?

Mysql-query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM game JOIN game_teams ON game.id = game_teams.game_id
    JOIN team_members ON game_teams.teams_id = team_members.team_id
WHERE start_date IS NOT NULL AND end_date IS NOT NULL AND members_username = 'user2'
```

This query retrieves more columns than columns in game table. Maybe I have to select just the columns that are in the game table?

I need something like this:

```
@Query("???")
Collection<Game> findUserPlayedGames(User user);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * "
        + " FROM game g JOIN game_teams gt ON g.id = gt.game_id "
        + "     JOIN team_members tm ON gt.teams_id = tm.team_id "
        + " WHERE g.start_date IS NOT NULL AND g.end_date IS NOT NULL AND tm.members_username = 'user2'",
        nativeQuery = true)
Collection<Game> findUserPlayedGames(User user);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing username as variable then follow below way and you are doing some joining in the query then there many columns so use return type as List<Object[]>

```
@Query(value ="SELECT * 
FROM game JOIN game_teams ON game.id = 
game_teams.game_id
JOIN team_members ON game_teams.teams_id = 
team_members.team_id
WHERE start_date IS NOT NULL AND end_date IS NOT NULL 
ANDD members_username = :username",   nativeQuery = true)

List<Object[]> 
findUserPlayedGamess(@Param("username)String userName);
```